# SwiftUI calls .onAppear for views that should not exist

Tags: swiftui

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import SwiftUI

let defaultDeck = Deck()

class Deck: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentCard: String? = nil
    
    func addCard() {
        self.currentCard = "NewCard"
    }
    
    func deleteCard() {
        currentCard = nil
    }
}

struct EditCardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var deck: Deck
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button("Delete") {
                // Perform save action here
                // hack to update the parent view
                deck.deleteCard()
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var deck: Deck
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hi!")
                if let currentCard = deck.currentCard {
                    Text("CurrentCard: \(deck.currentCard!)")
                        .onAppear {
                            print("OnAppear called, text: \(deck.currentCard!)", Date())
                        }
                } else {
                    Text("Out of cards!")
                }
                Button("Add") {
                    deck.addCard()
                }
                if let currentCard = deck.currentCard {
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditCardView(deck: deck)
                    } label: {
                        Text("edit")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 buttons: add card and edit card. Edit card leads to a different screen that has only 1 button: delete card.
Due to this:

```
if let currentCard = deck.currentCard {
    Text("CurrentCard: \(deck.currentCard!)")
        .onAppear {
            print("OnAppear called, text: \(deck.currentCard!)", Date())
        }
    }
```

I expect current card to be displayed only when it exists, and so it does if there is no .onAppear modifier.
However, adding the .onAppear modifier causes the closure to be called after pressing the "delete" button, even though there is no card anymore.
Why is this happening?
Is this some sort of ObservableObject misuse?
Or should I always expect .onAppear of the view to be called, even when they should not be displayed at all?

I've only bumped into this issue when I wanted to play sound in .onAppear code. The app looks as though everything is correctly, but the sound plays when it shouldn't.
I also only see this behaviour when there is a child view dismissal. Simply making a "delete" button in the parent view behaves correctly.

Comment: IMO this is a SwiftUI bug. Submit a feedback to Apple. meanwhile a workaround is quite simple for you (start `onAppear` form checking the condition again: `.onAppear { guard let currentCard = deck.currentCard else { return } ... }`

Comment: submitted: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/12881934